# Getting a table to redraw

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a view which is a big table. This table is populated from my array of data. This is all working well. The table drawing perfect.

I pop up another small overlay view where you can set some filters. The filter does its thing and the array of data that gets changed and the array changes in size so that there is more or less items to draw in the table.

When the filter overlay view disappears there is no change to the view with the big table.

So I am guessing I need to call something to update the table or get it to redraw. Is there some kinda of delegate method for this or whats the best way to get a table to completely refresh itself?

Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

should be called after you modify the data array, to redisplay the data.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView:

```
- (void)reloadData
```

Answer (score 0):

to reload table data use

```
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

Answer (score 0):

make a IBOutlet UItable *table1 and assign it to your table
then use
[table1 reloadData];